# How to extract hour part of timestamp to a new column in DataFrame Spark

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I want to extract the hour from current timestamp column  and store the hour value in a new column in the data frame. Please do help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the functions available for column operations:

For Scala:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df2 = df.withColumn("hour", hour(col("timestamp_column")))
```

For Python:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df2 = df.withColumn('hour', hour(col('timestamp_column')))
```

Reference:

- [org.apache.spark.functions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql.functions)
- [pyspark.sql.functions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql.functions)

Answer (score 9):

This should work:

```
val DF2 = DF1.withColumn("col_1", trim(DF1("col_1")))
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help

```
val df = Seq((" Virat ",18,"RCB"),("Rohit ",45,"MI "),(" DK",67,"KKR ")).toDF("captains","jersey_number","teams")

scala> df.show

+--------+-------------+-----+
|captains|jersey_number|teams|
+--------+-------------+-----+
|  Virat |           18|  RCB|
|  Rohit |           45|  MI |
|      DK|           67| KKR |
+--------+-------------+-----+

scala>val trimmedDF = df.withColumn("captains",trim(df("captains"))).withColumn("teams",trim(df("teams")))

scala> trimmedDF.show

+--------+-------------+-----+
|captains|jersey_number|teams|
+--------+-------------+-----+
|   Virat|           18|  RCB|
|   Rohit|           45|   MI|
|      DK|           67|  KKR|
+--------+-------------+-----+
```